# Google Maps not getting display in rails renderd screen

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

HI i am integrating google maps in my application if i create a new page then map is getting displayed perfectly but when i try to load it in renderd screen m unable to get the map. following is the my code for google map integration :

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(event) {
            initialize();
        });

 function initialize() {

   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.46249,-4.87793);
   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    message = "in the inistalise"
        document.write(message)

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
     }
    <% @latlng.each do |p| %>
  var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:new google.maps.LatLng(<%= (p.latitude).to_i %>,<%= (p.longitude).to_i %>),
      map: map,
      title:"City: <%=(p.city) %>  AND Total Clicks:  <%=(p.count) %>  ",
    });

 <% end %>

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-chart">
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/date_form", :locals => {:url => map_admin_dashboard_path, :div_id => "map"} %>

 <div id="map" style="width:770px; height:400px">
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fyi, I've created a gem to display google maps easily: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: It won't solve your problem but you could use `console.log("A message")` instead of `document.write`, it's a little cleaner.

Comment: How come you are using `$(document).ready`? This is a JQuery thingy if I am not mistaken but you don't include JQuery. I don't think this will work. If you use JQuery you could use `$('#map')` instead of `document.getElementById("map")`.

Comment: @apneadiving :- when i try to use your gem it gives error while installeing bundle install...

Comment: You're the first to report that. Could you open a new question and put the errors inside?